# How to get the color behind a JSlider

Tags: java, swing, graphics, colors, jslider

I there a way to get the color that is behind the slider portion of a JSlider? For Example, I made a program (see Image Below) that creates a gradient and requires the user to pick a color with a JSlider. Is there a way to get the color that the JSlider stops at?

[image]

Comment: How about a [`JColorChooser`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/colorchooser.html)?

Comment: That wouldn't work for what I am trying to accomplish. The purpose of this application is to match a given color with a blend of colors. A `JColorChooser` would kind of defeat the purpose.

Comment: Have you tried using the Robot class? (See my code below)

Comment: How is the background generated?

Comment: The background gets generated through `GradientPaint` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get a point on the slider you could use.

```
Color color = robot.getPixelColor((int)coord.getX(), (int)coord.getX())
```

The pseudo code would look like

```
 Robot robot = new Robot();
 int xValue = slider.getLocationOnScreen().x + (int)(slider.getValue()/(double)(slider.getMaximum()-slider.getMinimum()) * slider.getWidth() +.5);//Calculates distance of the sliders' position).
 int yValue = slider.getLocationOnScreen().y + slider.getHeight()/2;//Calculates a y-value to extract the pixel from. 
 Color color = robot.getPixelColor(xValue,yValue);
```